# Squares with different background colors

Tags: javascript, react.js, react-native

`Titles` is an array populated by numbers (1, 2 and 3). Depending on the number, a `Square` component should have a different background colour. Now, I don't think that having that the `switch` statements are the best way to make the condition. I'm sure there's a better way to make `Square`'s background depending on the mapped number.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
//import { getStatus, getPosition, genGrid } from '../actions';
import { CardSection, Square } from './common';


class MainMaze extends Component {

  generateMaze() {
    const { tiles } = this.props.grid;
    return (
      tiles.map((sq, i) => {
        switch (sq) {
          case 3:
            return <Square key={i} style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}>{sq}</Square>;
          case 2:
            return <Square key={i} style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue' }}>{sq}</Square>;
          default:
            return <Square key={i} style={{ backgroundColor: 'green' }}>{sq}</Square>;
        }
      }
    ));
  }
  render() {
    const { grid, position, status } = this.props;

    return (
      <View>
        <CardSection>
          <Text>{grid.cols}</Text>
        </CardSection>
        <CardSection>
          {this.generateMaze()}
        </CardSection>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    status: state.status,
    position: state.position,
    grid: state.grid
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MainMaze);
```

The `Square` component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

const Square = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={[styles.containerStyle, props.style]}>
      <Text>
        {props.children}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = {
  containerStyle: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#ddd',
    elevation: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    margin: 0,
    height: 30,
    width: 30
  }
};

export { Square };
```